# How to view results of JUnit 5 tests in IntelliJ 2019?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

When I run the Maven Lifecycle item `test`:

[image]

… I see this:

[image]

…which does tell me tests ran and some failed, but that is all it tells me. I expected to see a helpful window pane dedicated to JUnit 5 results handling as documented in [*Viewing and Exploring Test Results*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-and-exploring-test-results.html), and as shown in this screenshot taken from the documentation:

[image]

➥ How can I make IntelliJ show more helpful results of running unit tests as the documentation promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshots you posted represent are 2 different kinds of "*executions*" (for a lack of a better term). The first screenshot shows a Maven test execution, while the second displays an IJ unit-test config execution.

From your description you want the latter, and there are a few ways to achieve it, but the main idea is that you need to create/execute an IJ "Run/Debug Configuration", not a maven goal. **I suppose** IJ will register some sort of internal test listeners to capture the execution and results when executing a "*Run configuration*", but not when executing the Maven "*test*" goal.

Here are some of your options (these are also [described](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-run-debug-configuration-for-tests.html) in the same "*Testing*" section as your "[*Viewing and Exploring Test Results*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-and-exploring-test-results.html)" link, just above it):

1. In the "*Project*" pane, context-click your module. Select the desired menu item.
   (The "*Run/Debug*" items will automatically create your run configuration [see point 2 below], so depending on your setup you may have to make minor adjustments.)

[image: right click test options]

2. from the "*Run/Debug configs*" dropdown, select "*Edit configurations*" (or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>), and create your new JUnit/TestNg/etc configuration

[image: Edit run/debug configs menu]

[image: Ceate a new run/debug config]

3. From within a test class, click on the gutter icon next to the class name (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>)

[image: Run from test class]

4. From within a class press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to list the matching test classes (or to create new ones), select the ones that you want and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> to run them.

[image: Run from production class]

Tip: If you want to run your tests only through your "*Run/Debug*" configuration, and *not* as part of your Maven goals, you can disable the testing goal in Maven. Simply click the blue-lightning-bolt icon named “*Toggle "Skip Tests" Mode*” in the button bar of the "*Maven*" pane. This toggles running or not-running your Maven goal named `test`. Notice the label for `test` appears with strike-through text when toggled off. When toggled off, operations such as a Maven `install` will not run the tests.

[image: Screenshot of "Maven" pane with]

Comment: Yes, indeed, adding & running a "Run/Debug" configuration for "all tests" does run the tests and displays results in a testing-oriented pane as shown in the documentation. Thanks!